# Babel code in React component to display tasks

Tags: beginner, react.js, jsx, to-do-list, babel.js

I'm trying to think of ways to clean up this component in my app so it looks more readable to other devs. This is the best I came up with so far. It's not that bad, but I think it could be a lot better. What do you guys think? How would you clean this code up to make it more readable?

````
const DisplayTasks = ({ tasksArray, removeTask, crossOutTask }) => { 
  return (
    <div id="orderedList">
      <ol>
        {tasksArray.map((task, index) => (
          <li onClick={ () => crossOutTask(index) } key={index} >

            { task.crossedOut 
              ? <strike>{task.title}</strike> 
              : task.title }

            <button id="removeButton" onClick={ event => removeTask(event, index) } >
              Remove
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
};
```
````

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty good. I don't really have any big comments, since I found it pretty easy to read. Nits:

- you could remove the wrapping `div` with the id `orderedList`... The `ol` tag serves the same purpose, plus it's not a very specific name. I think it probably makes more sense to add a *class* to the `ol` with a value like `tasks`.
- Generally don't use the index as a key. React uses these to figure out what to redraw. If you have some sort of ID, use that; if not, you can probably just use the task title, or a title + index. You want this to be specific... if the key too specific the component will get redrawn too much (generally not a problem). If the key is to general, components will be "stale"... not redrawn with the proper values.

Look good!